# Проект с тестами не видит основную библиотеку

Tags: c++, cmake

Вот очень упрощенная структура моего проекта:

```
MI
|
| - Core
|   | foo.h
|   | foo.cpp
|   | foo_test.cpp
|   | CMakeLists.txt
|
| - Test
|   | CMakeLists.txt
|
| - CMakeLists.txt
```

При сборке проекта получается следующее:

```
MI
| - _build
|   | - Core
|       | - Debug
|         | Cored.dll
|         | Cored.lib
|       | - Release
|         | Core.dll
|         | Core.lib
|
|   | - Test
|       | - Debug
|         | Test.exe
|       | - Release
|         | Test.exe
|
| - Core
|   | foo.h
|   | foo.cpp
|   | foo_test.cpp
|   | CMakeLists.txt
|
| - Test
|   | CMakeLists.txt
|
| - CMakeLists.txt
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске текстов в студии (MI/_build/Test/Debug/Test.exe) не хватает библиотеки **Core.dll**. Как можно решить эту ситуацию? Нужно копировать фалы библиотеки? Или, может, библиотеку и тесты в одну папку помещать? В качестве ответа также можно ссылку на какой-нибудь проект, где можно посмотреть правильную реализацию. Если нужны какие-то cmake файлы, я дополню вопрос, их много и они все связаны.

Comment: Я бы просто папку с dll подбросил в path

Comment: Копировать надо будет не только все исполняемые файлы, но и еще файлы с отладочной информацией к ним

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой, но только на Linux. Помогло вот [это](https://r4nd0m6uy.ch/cmake-and-cpputest.html). Там сначала создается статическая библиотека на основе исходного кода программы (APP_LIB_NAME)

```
set(APP_LIB_SOURCE
    IFoo.cpp
    Foo.cpp
    Bar.cpp
)

add_library(${APP_LIB_NAME} ${APP_LIB_SOURCE})
```

, которая потом используется при компиляции тестов:

```
target_link_libraries(${TEST_APP_NAME} ${APP_LIB_NAME} ${CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS})
```